# What is an appropriate SE site to ask about understanding an algorithm of a dead language?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm working with an old system that uses an obscure language that is mostly dead at this point.

The original programmer did a number of very confusing things (I'm told it was for job security reasons) and trying to grok his original code is incredibly confusing. For example, there is a date function that seems to use 384 days in a year and 32 days in a month (though, I'm not really sure).

**What would be a good SE to ask for help in grokking this old, obscure, and confusing code?**

Comment: Questions on SE sites need to have value for more users then just you. Based on your description I doubt many visitors will find it useful what that code does. That could lead to a negative reception once posted. Theoretically "explain this code for me" can fly on SO but that needs a focussed and specific problem description. If it is old and obscure maybe Retro Computing is an option. I would try a chat room first before starting work on formulating a question for an SE site.

Comment: @rene yeah that's more or less what I thought. I thought about code golf, since there might be some masochist out there that enjoys solving such a puzzle, but that's not exactly the purpose of code golf.

Comment: Code Golf is definitely not it. Its chatroom might be worth trying ....

Comment: What obscure language? [COBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL)? Some [in-house language](https://blog.codinghorror.com/has-joel-spolsky-jumped-the-shark/)? Something else?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum The language/database system is called Eloquence.

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure a Hebrew leap year is related here, but I can't say without speaking to the guy who originally wrote the code. In this case, dates are stored as days since 1/1/1900 but are calculated by having 384 days a year and 32 days a month. This is for a brick and mortar retail point of sale system.

Comment: @Rob I meant Eloquence. https://eloquence.marxmeier.com/  While I said it was "dead" that's maybe not the best phrasing. It's still used (we use it!) but there's very few developers that know how or are willing to work on it.

Comment: There are at least [two questions about Eloquence](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+Eloquence+database+-Sofa+-Laravel&searchOn=3) on SO, you might try your luck there; be certain to follow their requirements for composing a good question. EG: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: ([From their site](https://eloquence.marxmeier.com/sales/info.html): *"Eloquence is supported through Marxmeier Software AG and Support partners worldwide. Access to technical support and the right to use the latest product versions requires an appropriate support contract."*)

Comment: 384 days sounds like a [lunar calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_calendar), like the [Islamic calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar), though with 13 lunar cycles rather than 12 lunar cycles (354 days). Each month is about 29 1⁄2 days (the [synotic orbital period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period) - 29 d 12 h 44 min 2.9 s (29.530589 days)). Could it be some kind of leap month to align with a solar calendar (like leap years 356/357 in the Julian/Gregorian calendar)? - some years in this calendar would have 12 lunar cycles and others 13 lunar cycles.

Comment: 13 lunar periods is 383.89766 days, which is close enough (off by about 3 hours).

Comment: Somewhat related: [International Fixed Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Fixed_Calendar). 13 months, but each month is always 28 days (to be divisible by 7 (days in a week)), 1 1/2 day less than the lunar cycle period. The number of days per year is then 364.

Comment: [This leads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_reform#13-month_calendars) [into a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunisolar_calendar) [Wikipedia rabbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_calendars) [hole. I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_calendar) [better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Irregular_weeks) [stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Days_of_week_of_holidays).

Comment: The last one has *"a common Hebrew calendar year can have a length of 353, 354 or 355 days, while a leap Hebrew calendar year can have a length of 383, 384 or 385 days."*